# How to calculate overall rating from multiple implicit feedback

Tags: recommender-system

I have data representing individual feedback ('like'/'not liked', represented in my data as 1/0 repesectively). I also have ancillary data on the length of time individuals have watched courses ('Time') and the number of series the individual has watched ('Number')

I would like to create an overall rating $R$ that includes the user feedback and the behavioural cues (Time and Number) to give a more nuanced score.

Some  papers on multiple  feedback propose that the individual feedback elements can be joined  as  $R=w1*r1+w2*r2...$ In my example  this may mean giving the "Like" table a higher weight while for number of series has smaller  weight. I have  read [collaborative filtering for  implicit feedback](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf) but  I couldn't find way how  set weights.

### Question:

Is there  any  strict  rule to  set weights  properly?

Answer (score -1):

In the context of the cited paper your weights represent how much your confidence increases with one of the actions (liking, number of series, etc.). Thinking about your business problem might give you already a good idea about the weights. For example, you might conclude that liking a a course is a much stronger signal than just watching it half-way through (this might even by a negative signal).

For a more thorough approach you could treat the weights as hyperparameters and tune them (if your sample is big enough to tune that many hyperparameters).

**An alternative approaches to try out:**

Train three different models (one for each implicit feedback feature). Then, you have to decide whether you want to combine the learned latent factors or the ranked lists of recommendations.